# how i can make a exactly field query in firestore?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have this structure:

```
[Collection] users
     [Document] id
            [Object] profile
                 [Field] photo: String
                 [Field] name: string
            [Object] user
                 [Field] lastname: String
                 [Field] name: string
```

Edit: [Database structure image](https://i.gyazo.com/110898d39ced3eaae318b9dbbd7546e6.png)

Now i just wanna get the 'photo' field. How?

Comment: Is your question asking how to get a single field instead of complete document ? or get documents where that photo field is equal to something.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.  Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: When you fetch a document in that collection, the `photo` field is included. What are you doing that's not working?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I just want to get a single field

Comment: @JayCodist That its working, but i dont need the whole document, i just need one field

Comment: You can't fetch just a field. You fetch the document, which will be an object containing the field